# Enabling the microphone in a browser using node.js and capturing the information spoken

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, watson

I have been struggling for a while and have been looking through many examples on how to enable the mic in a browser with Node.js. I have seen several Javascript examples but, I can't get the spoken content out of them and store it in variables. How can I enable the mic using Node.js? Will I need a specific npm package? I am currently working with the IBM Watson Speech to Text api. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enable the mic in the browser using a client side library.

Use the Speech-to-Text SDK here:

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk

And a working example here:

https://watson-speech.mybluemix.net/microphone-streaming.html

Comment: Hi @ItsMeRileyP, did this help?

Comment: Hay, @joe. Sorry for not responding, I was working on implementing the code you had given me and I just never got around to it. It has helped... A ton! Thank you so much! I don't want to mark it as "answered" just yet, because I am still working on getting everything set up. Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that streaming microphone will not work on any version of Safari. You will need to use FireFox, Chrome or IE to use streaming microphone into Watson Speech to Text. There's a YouTube tutorial on building a simple Bluemix App using Speech to Text here: (see Chapter 3) [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnJzIOiv6cVTaS8k90R3T9AlS_kf5XWmX)The supporting code is in a public git repo here: [Zero To Cognitive Repo](https://github.com/rddill-IBM/ZeroToCognitive)